# Tracking page visibility

Tags: google-analytics

I have a very long website with text to read.

There are no links on my page, it's all on one single pages.

I'm interested in tracking which part of the page the users spends most time reading.

Is this possible with Google Analytics and Google TagManager?

I searched through "User Timings", but I don't think that this helps me much.

Comment: You might want to look at scroll tracking. Events are fired every x% of the scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at scroll depth tracking. Events are fired every x% of the scroll. If the user doesn't scroll enough, they didn't find relevant content or engaging. User Timing can get skewed because of the aggregation of the `session time` and GA recording 00:00 for a bounced session.

Also use scroll depth instead of element visibility for tracking long form content. Element visibility is typically used when an element appears that shows up dynamically because of an interaction.

Google Tag Manager already has native `Scroll Depth Variable` that you can use to trigger the events.

For scroll tracking implementation refer to this link - 
https://www.simoahava.com/amp/analytics/scroll-depth-trigger-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a tool like CrazyEgg or Lucky Orange, these tools also save videos from the user interaction, so it's maybe more useful than just the raw metrics.
As @AnkDasCo said the Scroll Tracking is the Google Analytics way to go.

Comment: Would you prefer your suggestions over this method? -> https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/element-visibility-trigger-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Use scroll depth instead of element visibility. Element visibility is typically used when an element appears that shows up dynamically because of an interaction. For scroll tracking refer to this - https://www.simoahava.com/amp/analytics/scroll-depth-trigger-google-tag-manager/

Comment: @AnkDasCo Scroll Tracking=Scroll depth?

Comment: @tmighty sorry for the confusion, it is scroll depth tracking, one and the same thing.

Comment: @AnkDasCo Thank you. Could you make your comment the answer?